# How to read long cell values using OpenCSV?

Tags: java, opencsv

I am importing a csv file. I have a cell value something like 1.00E+13 while importing which has to be read as 10023000000000 (actual expanded value).
I am using OpenCSV.

Note: I achieved this by using apache POI for XLS and XLSX files, Since POI doesn't support CSV I am using OpenCSV.

POI's solution to above scenario is:

```
FormulaEvaluator objFormulaEvaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(hWorkbook);
HSSFCell cellValue = row.getCell(1);   //input as 1.00E+13
objFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(cellValue); //result as 10023000000000
```

How do I achieve this in OpenCSV?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably going to have to DIY something like `(long) Double.parseDouble("1.00E+13");`

Answer (score 0):

Kenny's answer is dead on if you are parsing the Strings from the csvReader yourself.  My only concern is that the csv file is strings so the input will have to be 1.0023E+13 not 1.00E+13.

All that said there is another way in opencsv and that is the CsvToBean class.  You create a class that has the values you want with public getters and setters then the CsvToBean will handle the conversions for you as the passing test below showed.

```
public class CsvToBeanDoubleTest {

    private static final double DOUBLE_NUMBER = 10023000000000d;

    private static final String TEST_STRING = "name,orderNumber,doubleNum\n" +
            "kyle,abc123456,10023000000000\n" +
            "jimmy,def098765,1.0023E+13 ";

    private CSVReader createReader() {
        return createReader(TEST_STRING);
    }

    private CSVReader createReader(String testString) {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(testString);
        return new CSVReader(reader);
    }

    private MockBean createMockBean(String name, String orderNumber, double num) {
        MockBean mockBean = new MockBean();
        mockBean.setName(name);
        mockBean.setOrderNumber(orderNumber);
        mockBean.setDoubleNum(num);
        return mockBean;
    }

    @Test
    public void parseBeanWithNoAnnotations() {
        HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MockBean> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MockBean>();
        strategy.setType(MockBean.class);
        CsvToBean<MockBean> bean = new CsvToBean<MockBean>();

        List<MockBean> beanList = bean.parse(strategy, createReader());
        assertEquals(2, beanList.size());
        assertTrue(beanList.contains(createMockBean("kyle", "abc123456", DOUBLE_NUMBER)));
        assertTrue(beanList.contains(createMockBean("jimmy", "def098765", DOUBLE_NUMBER)));
    }
}
```